# Blazor wasm with Microsoft Identity inside New Teams Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams, blazor-webassembly, teams-toolkit

I have an application in Blazor WebAssembly that use Microsoft Identity for autentication (Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal).

In previews Teams this application loads very well in a Tab or in teams tab (WebSite), using popup flow.
The problem is new Teams dosent show any popup from WebAssembly.Msal. If i set redirect flow dosent work because inside teams this is on iframe. So what are my options here?

Can i open a native teams dialog like office addins does and run the autentication flow?

Tks